# How to create a flask server to generate data to feed into kafka?

Tags: python, flask, server, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a server that reads a large amount of data from the local machine or from s3 (will be json or some row-based), and then spit out each row to.. somewhere so that kafka can ingest this data.
How can I make this server with flask and control how much it outputs per second or minute?

Comment: Why do you need flask? Your python script can just read the data in and send it straight to a kafka topic. [Here's](https://github.com/code-and-dogs/liveMaps/blob/master/busdata1.py) some code that does that.

Comment: omg thanks. But how can I control how much it outputs per second or minute?

Comment: In this particular code, data is being read straight from a JSON file on disk. To simulate a flow of data from a real stream, this code loops through each data point and applies a delay using `sleep(1)` between write of the producer to the topic. So, in this example, you can control how frequently the producer writes to the topic by changing the argument of `sleep`. The kafka consumer will read each message placed onto the topic as soon as it's computationally possible to do so.